# Registrar tempo de execução no python

Tags: python, timer

No Python, preciso fazer algo do tipo:

```
timer.start()

***Imagine um código de várias linhas aqui***

timer.stop()
print("Tempo de execução: " + timer)
```

Pode ser em segundos, minutos qualquer coisa, alguém pode me dar uma ajuda de mais ou menos como posso fazer?

Comment: Já tentou usar o módulo `timeit`? https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/timeit.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar o módulo`time`.

```
import time
t1 = time.time()

# código aqui

tempoExec = time.time() - t1
print("Tempo de execução: {} segundos".format(tempoExec))
```

A linha `time.time()` retorna o tempo em segundos desde 1 de janeiro de 1970, e a linha `time.time() - t1` representa a variação de tempo, ou seja, quanto tempo o programa demorou para rodar.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi, você esta querendo `calcular` o tempo de `execução` do programa.

Para que esta questão tenha uma resposta mais evidente, vamos supor que estamos querendo `calcular` o tempo de execução que o programa leva para calcula o `fatorial` de um número.

Neste caso vamos analisar apenas o cálculo do `fatorial`.

Para isso devemos utilizar o seguinte algoritmo...

```
from time import time

while True:
    try:
        n = int(input('Digite um valor inteiro: '))
        if n <= 0:
            print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas inteiros maiores que "0"!\033[m')
        break
    except:
        print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas números inteiros!\033[m')

instante_inicial = time()
print(f'\033[32mO fatorial de {n} é:')
prod = 1
cont = 0
for c in range(n, 1, -1):
    cont += 1
    x = (n - cont)
    prod *= c
    print(f'{x}', end='')
    print(' x ' if x > 1 else ' = ', end='')
print(f'{prod}')
instante_final = time()
diferenca = (instante_final - instante_inicial) * 1000

print(f'O tempo de execução do calculo do fatorial foi de: {diferenca:.2f} ms')
```

[Veja aqui](https://repl.it/join/hidmlwbc-solkarped) o funcionamento do programa.

Observe que o tempo foi definido em `milissegundos`.

Neste caso definir duas variáveis que foram: `instante_inicial` e `instante_final`. Em seguida, calculei a `diferença` entre elas e `multipliquei` por `1000` uma vez que pretendia fornecer o resultado em `milissegundos` `(ms)`.

Observe também que, quanto maior for a complexidade do cálculo maior será a demora de execução.

Outra coisa, o tempo de demora na execução de um algoritmo é `diretamente proporcional` à capacidade do hardware da máquina, isto é, capacidade de processamento e memória. Em outras palavra, um algoritmo que leva `2.00` ms para ser executado em uma máquina de processador `dual core`, levará bem menos tempo para ser executado em uma máquina de processador `i5`. Além disso, outras variáveis devem ser levadas em consideração. Por exemplo, tipo de `linguagem de programação`, se é uma linguagem `interpretada` ou `compilada`, etc.